# Convex function in its interior

Tags: analysis

Let $f$ be a convex function on an open subset of $R^{n}$. How to prove $f$ is continuous in the interior of its domain.

For $n=1$, let $f$ be convex on the set $(a,b)$ with $a<s<t<u<b$

Then using the inequality $\frac{f(t)-f(s)}{t-s} \leq \frac{f(u)-f(s)}{u-s} \leq \frac{f(u)-f(t)}{u-t} $
We can prove it for $n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the solution in the following lecture note
[enter link description here](http://orion.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/henry/teaching/f09/663.f09/663miscfiles/solns1f09.pdf)